# Webview as drag destination?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, webview

OK, so here's what I need (though I still have found no real answer to my questions) :

- I have a plain and simple `WebView`
- I need to be able to drop items on that `WebView`.

I've tried via the `WebUIDelegate` and its methods, even `registerForDraggedTypes`, but still without success.

Any ideas? Is there anywhere a complete example of how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it in my application, followings are the key points, if you still looking for it,

Let it accept drop into the webview

```
[self registerForDraggedTypes:
 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:MyPrivateTableViewDataType,NSFilenamesPboardType,nil]];
```

Handle Dragging entered to verify / validate the item which is being dragged.

```
- (NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:MyPrivateTableViewDataType] ) {
        if (sourceDragMask & NSDragOperationGeneric) {
            return NSDragOperationGeneric;
        }
    }

}
- (BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender{
    NSPasteboard *pboard;

    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:MyPrivateTableViewDataType] ) {
        // Only a copy operation allowed so just copy the data
        return YES;
    }
    else if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType] ) {
        return YES;

    }
    return NO;
}
```

and finally perform/complete the drag-drop

```
- (BOOL)performDragOperation:(id < NSDraggingInfo >)sender{

    NSPasteboard *pboard;

    pboard = [sender draggingPasteboard];

    if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:MyPrivateTableViewDataType] ) {
        // Only a copy operation allowed so just copy the data
            return YES;
        }
        else{
            return NO;
        }

    } else if ( [[pboard types] containsObject:NSURLPboardType] ) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromPasteboard: pboard];
        NSString *filePath= [url path];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I have already solved it, but probably forgot to post my solution answer. Thanks a lot for contributing to the community! :-)